# How connect to Azure Key Vault from java backend using Azure Java SDK?

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault, azure-java-sdk

Followed this documentation:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-secrets/README.md

I get the error:

AADSTS900382: Confidential Client is not supported in Cross Cloud request

Note that this is with government cloud.

Is it just the case that the Java app must be hosted on the same server in the cloud as azure key vault? Because that doesn't really make sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, that is because  all of the SDKs default to using `https://login.microsoftonline.com` as the Azure Active Directory authority host. Each of the other clouds have different authority host endpoints. So we need to change authority host when we create `DefaultAzureCredential`.

For example. I use the sdk `Azure Identity Version 1.1.0-beta.4`

1. Install SDK

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-beta.4</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

2. Code

```
/** 
 * the class `KnownAuthorityHosts` has the all cloud Azure Active Directory authority enpoint :
 * https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.knownauthorityhosts?view=azure-java-preview
*/
DefaultAzureCredential cred = new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().
                 authorityHost(KnownAuthorityHosts.AZURE_US_GOVERNMENT)
                 .build();
SecretClient client = new SecretClientBuilder()
        .vaultUrl(<your-vault-url>)
        .credential(cred )
        .buildClient();
```

For more details, please refer to the [article](https://blog.jongallant.com/2020/02/azure-identity-other-clouds/)

Comment: I missed that this is Java. I followed the article for .NET and that works! Thank you! For any other C# people, `KeyClient` is now `SecretClient`.